# Accessing servlet served by Tomcat requires Windows Security authentication

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, windows-security

I am running Tomcat from eclipse using sysdeo plugin.  It deploys all the apps properly and I can access the manager using the username specified in the tomcat-uses config.  One particular application/servlet returns a 401 error for all requests send to it.

When I go to its url directly it prompts a Windows Security dialog requesting for username and password.  It says "The server localhost at {{Servlet Name}} requires a username and password.  Warning:  this server is requesting that your username and password be sent in an insecure manner (basic authentication without a secure connection.".

I have tried providing the tomcat and the system username and password but it fails and shows the same screen again.

```
The logs record the following:
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Jan/2013:14:15:51 -0500] "GET /ServletURI HTTP/1.1" 401 951
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [10/Jan/2013:14:21:41 -0500] "GET /ServletURI HTTP/1.1" 401 951
```

I know this is has to do with authentication settings, but I am not sure where exactly to look into.  Any suggestions?  Thank you.

Comment: Is it really a windows security issue, or might it be http basic authentication? You might check web.xml for security constraints.

Comment: Is there anything particular that I could check/set in conf/web.xml.

Comment: In the web.xml, from the app hosting the sevlet you are trying to access, there should be a <security-constraint> tag.